# Is a chained if...else expression in python faster than if..elif..else statements?

Tags: python

I wrote this quick test script to check, but I only have access to a bash console on pythonanywhere right now, and I am not getting consistent times.

```
def a():
    x = 0
    for i in xrange(1000):
        if i%2==0 and i%3==0:
            x += 3
        elif i%2==0 or i%3==0:
            x += 2
        else:
            x += 1

def b():
    x = 0
    for i in xrange(1000):
        x += 3 if i%2==0 and i%3==0 else (2 if i%2==0 or i%3==0 else 1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run("for i in xrange(1000): a()")
    cProfile.run("for i in xrange(1000): b()")
```

I'm looking to speed up some code, and I am wondering if there is any big speed difference between these two different ways of doing it.

Comment: Use `timeit` to compare these. I'd expect the difference to be so minimal as to make no difference.

Comment: They should both "short-circuit", or return as soon as the first valid possibility is available.  They should each only evaluate as much as they need to, minor if any real difference in performance.

Comment: `timeit` shows `a` is 5% faster.

Comment: @NPE Yes I know, I was just giving a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Pavel Anossov says, a is faster:

```
import timeit

def a():
    x = 0
    for i in xrange(1000):
        if i%2==0 and i%3==0:
            x += 3
        elif i%2==0 or i%3==0:
            x += 2
        else:
            x += 1

def b():
    x = 0
    for i in xrange(1000):
        x += 3 if i%2==0 and i%3==0 else (2 if i%2==0 or i%3==0 else 1)


test_a = timeit.Timer(a)
test_b = timeit.Timer(b)

print min(test_a.repeat(3, 1000))
print min(test_b.repeat(3, 1000))
```

Outputs

```
0.573258876801
0.591067075729
```

When we replace **xrange** with **range** (xrange is gone in 3.x) the difference is none almost, like others say. I have tested it on 2.6

Adequatly:

```
0.597590923309
0.598859071732
```